# How to rerender the View for angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am navigating from my video_component and navigating back to the same video_component again but with a different video in the view.

When I click

```
nextVideo(){
    this.param = ++i;
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/video/${this.param}`);
    });
```

The URL parameters change and the code for the video changes. But for these changes to take effect I need to reload the component again because I have and external js library that loads the videos when the component template gets rendered.

Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: can you share some more code? It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @JanR Sure, so when I click next video I update this div with a new video.id
`<div id="videoframe" class="{{video.id}}">`
But I need to refresh the template to render the new video manually to get that video to render. Is there anyway to get the component to reload without refreshing the whole page?